# Translating words in array in javascript file in django

Tags: javascript, django, internationalization, django-translated-fields

I installed the JavaScript Catalog for translating text in javascript files as explained in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.views.i18n

That works well. I can create the PO translation files and als make and compile the translations. For example:

`gettext("my-translation")`

will work just fine.

Now I want get an array from an API call which looks like this:

`let arr = ["red", "green", "yellow", "blue"]`.

I don't know how I can use `gettext` to create the translations for each word in the array. I tried to map it with `arr.map(i => gettext( + i + ")"));`. I also tried to add it to the whole array with `gettext(arr)`, but no success.

My websearches did not help me. I cannot change the representation of the array, so I need to do this in the frontend.

Is there any trick for this? Thanks for any help and hints.

Edit:

- I tried `arr.map(i => gettext( + i + ")"));`. This adds the last ")" into the string so it does not work
- I tried `arr.map(i => gettext(i));` This returns the same array without adding the gettext
- I tried arr.map(i => gettext() + i); This adds me an "undefined" to the string

I tried other combinations which I can't remember

Comment: I am getting the array with an ajax request. There are no translations in the DB. The colors are choice fields in the model, wich I tried to translate, but whenever I always only get the unstranslated versions back

Comment: Is there a typo here? `arr.map(i => gettext( + i + ")"));` Why do you add ")" to the string passed to the `gettext`?

Comment: Well I tried a couple of ways. I edited my question to describe what the outcome was

Comment: The second one `arr.map(i => gettext(i));` should be the good one. If you get the same input string then make sure you translated the colour names, compiled the .po/.mo files and reload the page where you load the javascript catalog.

Comment: @Marc You are right. `arr.map(i => gettext(i));` indeed works if I add the color translations manually. What does not work is `compilemessages`, that's why I thought I am doing it wrong. But adding it manaually to the `PO` file and then compiling does the trick. Thank you very much for the valuable hint. That solved it :)